# Foundation user login problem

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, login

How do I stop domain users having to log in when accessing SP foundation?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the site in the local internet zone in the browser (I assume it is Internet Explorer)? Then you should verify the settings at:
`Internet Options / Security / Local Intranet / Custom level... / User Authentication` - it schould be `Automatic logon only in Intranet zone`
Otherwise you can set this value for other zones as

```
Automatic logon with current user name and password
```

although that is not considered to be secure.

You should of course test the settings first on a single PC, then set it (or let the user set it) either manually on each other, or push the changes via Policy (I assume the PCs are part of an Active Directory domain) or maybe via a login script.

Comment: Thanks so I would have to add the site to intranet at each users PC?